# Secure token google API PERMISSION_DENIED : “Request had insufficient authentication scopes.” error

Tags: php, laravel, google-api

Here is my response:

```json
{
   "error":{
      "code":403,
      "message":"Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
      "status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"
   }
}
```

I tried with scopes `openid`, `profile`, `email`, https://mail.google.com/ but still getting insufficient authentication scopes.

[image]

After getting the access token I also get id_token that id_token I need to pass in params and in request I passed scopes.

Can anyone tell what permission I need to set up for my app in the API console?

Comment: What was the request? Can you share some code?

Comment: I have attached the image please check.